# WPF Horizontal Scrollbar is not visible

Tags: wpf, scrollbar

I have a Grid inside ScrollViewer. Grid has only one columns and many rows. I add controls into grid rows. The problem is I can see VerticalScrollBar when I am adding controls but I cannot see HorizontalScrollBar although I add very wide controls.
My xaml looks like the following

```
<ScrollViewer>  
    <Grid>  
        rows ...  
    </Grid>  
</ScrollViewer>
```

Thanks,
ant.

Comment: Now I found the solution. When I add StackPanel under ScrollViewer, it works. It becomes <ScrollViewer><StackPanel><Grid> .... But still don't know why <ScrollViewer><Grid>... is not working.

Answer (score 14):

Set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility of the ScrollViewer to "Auto" or "Visible".

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <Grid>
   ... rows ...
   </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```